# JUnit Test in java

Tags: java, junit, cucumber

I have a question:

I have such two methods:

```
@When("^I start playing restaurant game$")
public void I_start_playing_restaurant_game() throws Throwable 
{

}

@Then("^I should see \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void I_should_see(String arg1) throws Throwable {


}
```

These test methods are generated from this BDD:

```
Feature: Restaurant starts game

As a player
I want to start a game
So that I can play the restaurant game.

    Scenario: Create a restaurant for player
        Given The "restaurant" is created with the name "Kardesler Restaurant"
         And The "player" is created with the name "Mehmet"
         And The restaurant budget is initialised to 450000
        When I start playing restaurant game
        Then I should see "Welcome to Kardesler Restaurant Game!"
         And I should see "Thank you, Mehmet."
         And I should see "The starting budget equals to 450 000"
```

And I have such two test methods:

```
@Test
public void testI_start_playing_restaurant_game()
{

}

@Test
public void testI_should_see()
{

}
```

How can I manage to test these two methods, actually I'm new in JUnit testing cases, so I need help in this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you would be looking to test [side effects](http://junit.org/faq.html#atests_4) of your void methods. You generally want negative and positive tests. A negative test is one where you test the system by giving invalid data. A positive test is one where you pass valid data. Do you only have those 2 methods? If so, you might want to think about splitting that code up into a few methods, each of which does one well defined task. Breaking it down will make it: a) reusable and b) easier to test

Answer (score 2):

Cucumber uses steps definition files as the glue to link the `@Given` `@When` `@Then` annotations with the feature file. In that case your steps file will look like

```
public class RestaurantSteps {

    @Given("The \"restaurant\" is created with the name (.*)")
    public void setRestaurantName(String name) {
       ...
    }

    // @And methods omitted 

    @When("^I start playing restaurant game$")
    public void startPlaying() {
     ...
    }

    @Then("^I should see \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void checkWhatISee(String itemSeen) {
        // verify item seen...
    }

    ....
}
```

The Cucumber test runner will read the tests from the feature file itself rather than having individual test methods:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
public class RestaurantTest {  
}
```